# Making div background same height as body

Tags: html, css, background, height

i have been trying to solve this for like 2 hours now.. tried multiple guides, nothing worked.

Here is my css:

```
body {
margin:0;
background:url('chalk.jpeg');
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.welcome{
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(38, 36, 15, 0.7);
}
```

However, for some reason, the page looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peive.png

I want the welcome div background to be on top of the body background image until the end of the page. Tried many solutions but nothing would work.

Comment: Basically I want to stretch the welcome div background to the bottom of the page. Nothing is under it.

Comment: The background of the welcome div has a 0.7 opacity, so the body image will still be visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with *viewport units* where the `body` *element* takes `100%` of the *viewport height* with the `height: 100vh`, then just *stretch* the `.welcome` *div* with `height: 100%`:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1600x900') no-repeat center center; /* modified */
  background-size: cover; /* recommended / also try the "contain" */
}

.welcome {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(38, 36, 15, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome">welcome div</div>
```